# Why did Redis run out of memory even with maxmemory volatile-lru?

Tags: redis

A few days ago my Redis instance went down. All new write attempts failed with this error:

```
OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'
```

It only recovered after I flushed all the data. It runs in a VPS that has 24gb of RAM and only runs Redis, with this configuration:

```
maxmemory 20gb
maxmemory-policy volatile-lru
save ""
```

I use this instance to store sessions (notice though that persistence is disabled). Every session is written into Redis with an expiration time of 2 days, that means that all the keys have a TTL:

```
# Keyspace
db0:keys=1426936,expires=1425758,avg_ttl=87980766
```

Then why did it run out of memory? If the eviction policy is volatile-lru and all the keys have an expiration time set, why did it failed when it reached the maxmemory setting instead of evicting keys to free up memory?

Another thing to consider: the load of my application is very constant and stable, no peaks. The sessions are stored with an expiration time of 2 days. Now it's been six days running since I restarted the instance and flushed all, and Redis reports used_memory_human:781.54M. But when I check my server stats, I can see that the memory usage had been slowly increasing until the incident. And when I say slowly is really slowly: it took almost an year to reach the maxmemory=20gb limit.

But wait! How is that possible if sessions expire in two days? Could the incident be related to fragmentation ratio? I mean, sessions expire in two days, and all the time new sessions are being written to Redis. Is it possible that fragmentation ratio increased slowly during an year, making Redis fail regardless it had been configured with an eviction policy?

Or is there another theoretical situation where Redis can't free up memory fast enough? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you test with `maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru`?

Comment: I'll give it a try, though I can'tt test it in production. I'll try to reproduce the setup in a test server (but the load won't be the same). Do you have reasons to believe that the issue could be a bug in the volatile-lru policy?

Comment: Not necessarily a bug. volatile-lru is dependent on users implementation while allkeys-lru is not. Successful tests with allkeys-lru would add another perspective to the issue.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm not sure if I got you right about volatile-lru being dependent on users implementation, if there is any extra documentation I should read, I would appreciate you sharing it :)
Anyway, I've already changed it to allkeys-lru, but the server in production has now a lot of available RAM, it won't reach the limit for a long time. I'll deploy another server and will try to reproduce the error. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! About volatile-lru, it depends on expire time which requires to be set on each key individually by user. That way it depends on users implementation.

Comment: Ok, I understand. In my case all keys have an expiration time. I've made a simple test setting maxmemory to only 10mb and Redis evicted keys as expected (with both policies volatile-lru and allkeys-lru). That still leaves me with the same doubt: why did it fail on production with the same setup? Could the total amount of keys and its individual size be the source of the problem? The instance that failed in production handles millions of keys which size is a few bytes only. Could it be a problem? I keep trying to figure out what happened in order to prevent future incidents :/

Comment: I've edited my question with a few details that led me to think this could be a fragmentation problem maybe :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of testing and reading, I conclude that the incident was caused by memory fragmentation. I've been able to solve it turning on "activedefrag".

It turns out that memory fragmentation is something to expect in certain scenarios. Scenarios like mine: a Redis instance that handles millions of sessions, that is, a lot of small new keys are constantly being written, and also being deleted (because of expiration).

I was able to verify this: a few days after the incident, having flushed the data and restarted Redis, I saw how mem_fragmentation_ratio went increasing very slowly, from 1.05 up to 2 or even more!
Then I turned on activedefrag and mem_fragmentation_ratio started to decrease until 1.05 again.
Now it's been a week since it's running smoothly and mem_fragmentation_ratio never goes beyond 1.08 :)

In case you have doubts, I can say that the performance cost of turning on activedefrag is almost negligible.

Here is some interesting readings:
https://serverfault.com/questions/971804/are-there-situations-were-activedefrag-should-be-kept-disabled-in-redis-5-with